# Do two installations of Oracle SQL Developer on the same machine conflict?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I already have **oracle SQL developer** installed in my machine. I want to install another **oracle SQL developer** in my computer that I want to use for my personal web application. Of course I can work with one SQL developer, but in order to ease my maintenance I am planing to have two.

So, do they conflict? Can I run my applications smoothly?

Comment: Two different versions?  if not, then why not just launch two instances?  you do realize you can have multiple connections right? and just "Choose" which connection to use...

Comment: xQbert , thanks for your comment. Actually version does not matter in my case. Its not the fact of consideration. But yes, both of them may be the latest version, because I am installing them in very short interval. Because the one I have right now is given from my school, and the licence may be expired soon. So I am thinking installing a new one for my own use may cause conflict?

Comment: I've had multiple versions installed; and not run into conflicts.  I've found that I only use the latest version though.  So I'd just uninstall the old and install the new. and run multiple instances if needed.  though multiple sql files can serve the same purpose.  but if I want to use different users for the same database, I'll have multiple instances of the application open.

Comment: There's no time limited license for SQL Developer so don't worry about expiry. They'll tend to pick up the same 'local' data (eg from under %APPDATA% in Windows) so two installations won't give you much benefit.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can have two copies of SQL Developer 'installed' on your computer. There's not an install process - there's nothing written to the registry for example, and there's no un-installer.

You unzip the application to a directory, and run the EXE.

SQL Developer will write its preferences to your User AppData Roaming profiles folder. If they're the same exact version #, they'll share a parent directory, but there is a system_cache folder that can handle multiple instances of the app.

The framework uses the system_cache folder under user settings to ...
1. Speed up SQL Developer startup.
2. Persist certain settings if multiple instances are opened. Each additional instance creates a system_cache_N, where N=1,2,..
[image]

In your scenario, I can't think why you would need to do this. You could simply start up the application twice - it would have the same net effect.

> > So, do they conflict? Can I run my applications smoothly?
> >     No. And, yes. But you don't need to do this.

Comment: > *In your scenario, I can't think why you would need to do this.*  
To put my two cents in, I'm considering to use the two instances for local and remote development, because I want to turn on auto commit on local and have it turned off for prod connections.

Comment: Autocommit will at some point HURT YOU...seriously consider never ever using it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have 2 instance of sql developer on same machine without conflicting each other. They both can share same TNS file if you want to or keep them separately.

I have used 2 instances of it and never faced any issue. In my case they were or different version, but that doesn't matter.